# When will Google Apps API authorization of Google Apps Marketplace v1 be available?

Tags: google-api, google-apps-marketplace

I cannot find Google announcement of the abolition period of Google Apps Marketplace v1 but I thought Google Apps API authorization of Google Apps Marketplace v1 will be work until April 20, 2015 because OAuth 1.0 will work until it in accordance with the deprecation policy.
However I cannot think so because Google [announced](https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v1migratev2)  that UpgradeableApp API( that is Marketplace v2 migration API) will be available until the end of Q3 2014.

I have 3 questions:

1. When the abolition period of Marketplace v1? If Google already
   announced it on web site, please tell me the web site URL.
2. Could Marketplace v1 applications be affected in the abolition of
   UpgradeableApp API?
3. Can Installed Marketplace v1 application use Google Apps API until
   April 20, 2015 if Marketplace v1 was closed before April 20, 2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) 20th April 2015
2) Yes, they will be removed from Marketplace after 30th September 2014 (if not upgraded)
3) Yes existing base can continue using till April 20th

All above details were sent my email to all developers I beleive, didn't you receive it?

Comment: I didn't receive it. (I don't have published application. Could developers that has published application receive it?)
When did you sent it?If the Web site of the same content, please tell me the URL.

Comment: Ok then it must have been sent to published app developers. Email dated May 26. The Email looked tailored with lots of bits and pieces from google literature, so I don't think there is any single place where you will find all the information. anyways the most important info is the timeline and you now know!